# Defect status types in HP QC

Tags: testing, hp-quality-center, defects

I'm using HP QC to manage defects (just started) and had a question regarding the various defect status types....

We have:

1. New - new defect
2. Open - ??
3. Active - defect is being investigated
4. Fixed - dev team have issued a fix-need retest
5. Ready For Test - self explanatory

I know there are other status' but I'm not entirely sure of the meaning of open in particular...

I.e in what instances is a defect open

Answer (score 1):

In a well organized defect management system different (user)roles are defined. 
Each step in the process is maintained by a certain role.

Open means that the defects is checked by a senior and can be assigned or picked up by a solver.

For example:

1. A developer/tester logs a defect -> status becomes new.
   The developer/tester can't change the status to open/active or whatever. The defect just sits there waiting.
2. A testmanager (or defect coordinator/senior tester) checks the defect. (completeness, validity, duplicate etc). When the defect is ok, he changes the status to open. He can also assign a solver.
3. When a solver starts on working on the defect, he changes the status to active. Everyone can see who is busy working on this defect (investigating or solving).
4. Solver fixes defect and changes status to fixed.
5. Testmanager collects all fixed defects and assigns testers to them. Status change to Ready for (re)test.

etc.